# how to get user's group data from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As the changelog Facebook API upgrading from v2.3 to v2.4, we can't use the scope user_groups by v2.4 app anymore

> the user_groups permission has been deprecated. Developers may continue to use the user_managed_groups permission to access the groups a person is the administrator of. This information is still accessed via the /v2.4/{user_id}/groups edge which is still available in v2.4.

Is there any solutions to get group data?
I'm using Java with RestFb library

Comment: Come on! You don't necessarily need to use v2.4. It hasn't even been a day.
Use 2.3 instead, simple.

Comment: well, it will be gone in 90 days, so it does not matter which version you are using.

Comment: @luschn NO! It will be available until July 8, 2017 i.e. 2 years. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog.

Comment: "90-day deprecations (effective Tuesday, October 6, 2015)" - from the changelog. it will only be available for 90 more days. it would be pointless to keep the permission anyway, because you don´t get it approved in the review process.

Comment: OK! Sorry for the mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `user_managed_groups` for access to groups you manage, as you can read in the message. It´s not possible to access groups you don´t manage anymore. The API endpoint stays the same: `/me/groups`.

Comment: but i need to get data from groups which I am just a member, too

Comment: that´s not possible anymore with v2.4.

Comment: actually, it will be gone for every app in 90 days, not just v2.4 apps.